# Problem in importing chessboard.js in vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, chessboard.js

I am trying to import [chessboard.js](https://chessboardjs.com/) on my jetstream-vue application. After creating the project I ran
`npm install @chrisoakman/chessboardjs`
and it's in my node_modules folder. But when i tried `import Chessboard from '@chrisoakman/chessboardjs'` on app.js it shows error as

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@chrisoakman/chessboardjs' in '/home/user/project-chess/resources/js'
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 9:0-51
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/css/app.css
```

Is there any other way I should try to import it or from to a different file than app.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chrisoakman/chessboardjs can't be imported, since it doesn't export anything.

Look at the code, at the end it says:

```
  // TODO: do module exports here
```

Comment: oh, just checked that. So, i have to write export code now. Or is there any other way in which i could use the module functions without importing.

Comment: Perhaps you can learn something here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-chessboard